# I found this pic of a game on an advertisement, does anyone know what it's called?

Tags: game-identification

[image]

I was on the web just searching and I came across this character, and it reminded me of the endless fun I had with this game. I kept searching for the game with no success.

Does anyone know what it's called?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The game is called Sling, it is a Flash based game by the Edis Brothers,

A playable version can be found here:

http://www.miniclip.com/games/sling/en/

[image: Image of Sling confirmation]

Comment: ezone made the best games back in the day